# Is creating a lot of UIViews in UIViewController a good practice for storyboards? Does it have any impact on application like memory?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Today I heard about new approach of design views in storyboard

Lets consider one page contain image , label and button now out storyboard as follow

1] our one UIViewController divides in three part i.e 3 UIViews for 3 components like one `UIView` for image
2] for keep image responsive take another `UIView` and keep imageView inside that and then set constraints and keep wight and height of imageView aspect ratio.
 3] I given different colour for different UIViews for understanding
final hierarchy is as below

[image]

So as per screenshot you can see view are more responsive and changes made in one UIView is not reflect is another one and our hierarchy of view are maintained .

Finally come to the questions 
1] is this approach correct? 
2] is there any impact of this much UIView views on application in terms of memory and performance?

Comment: thanks @AjinkyaSharma for corrections

Comment: He , While Answering this question , please suggest a good approach of creating responsive app .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this method a lot and I realise this approach solve lot of problems of setting constraints. This approach is similar as Bootstrsp . We are going to divide hole screen by UIViews and Finally put our main design views in it. Till now I don't know what is bad impact of this approach in application in terms of memory and speed. That I will explain in future.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer on first question:**

The approach how to handling lot of views? No it is not correct. If you had lot of views in scrollView use UITableView or UICollectionView, because of better handling, reusing and layouting - features provided by UIKit for free. If you have lot of views on one screen without scrolling - try to use UIStackView - it will provide you lot of automatic layouting and very easy editing and updating layouts instead of using autolayout / layout masks. UIStackView can be considered as AutoLayout generator machine.

**Answer on second question:**

No. Using large storyboards has no much bigger impact on memory and performance, than generating it via code.

**There is two main problems with storyboards:**

1) Large storyboard has performance impact on XCode. Especially with older Macs.

2) If two or more people working in one storyboard simultaneously, you need to be aware, not to edit same ViewController together, or creating new, otherwise you will have repository conflicts (same as 2 persons edit same piece of code at same time), but you have to resolve it in xml, what is readable, but it takes some time to understand.

Comment: he thanks for answering , but you didn't get my question . It is not about using UIViews under scrollView . My simple question is using UIViews for each component . Like in Bootstrap we divide hole screen in several parts like that in UIViewController adding multiple UIViews for divide hole screen as per actual design of our page.